# Checkbox not displaying value

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have set up a simple todo in vanilla js

https://jsfiddle.net/mz9ecc3d/ (quick side note, how do you get javascript and html linked in jsfiddle? doesn't seem recognize my function)

```
  let input = document.getElementById('todoInput').value;
  let checkbox = document.createElement("input")
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox'
  let label = document.createElement("label")
  label.textContent = input
  checkbox.appendChild(label)
  let output = document.getElementById('todoList');
  output.appendChild(checkbox)
```

however, locally I can get the checkbox appearing but no value next to it. I couldn't work out why and read somewhere I might need a label so have appended that and it is all coming through in the console correctly, just on the screen it displays a checkbox with nothing next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> checkbox.appendChild(label)
> ```

Input elements are void elements. They cannot have children.

If you want to put the label next to the checkbox, then you have to put it *next* to it and not inside it.

```
output.appendChild(checkbox);
output.appendChild(label);
```

That said, a label needs to be associated with a form control.

There are two ways to do that:

## With a for attribute

```
checkbox.setAttribute("id", "something_unique");
label.setAttribute("for", "something_unique");
output.appendChild(checkbox);
output.appendChild(label);
```

… but that requires you generate a unique ID each time.

## By putting the checkbox inside the label

```
let input = document.getElementById('todoInput').value;

let checkbox = document.createElement("input")
checkbox.type = 'checkbox'

let label = document.createElement("label")
label.appendChild(checkbox);
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));

let output = document.getElementById('todoList');
output.appendChild(label)
```

… so, in conclusion: Put the checkbox inside the label instead of next to it.

Comment: great answer. will accept when it allows me. was close!

Comment: addTodo function will not be defined  in your fiddle cause you javascript is added inside window.onload by fiddle and onclick will not have reference to it.

Comment: You need to add your function to window to make it work on fiddle

Answer (score -1):

Here is the fixed function:

```
function addTodo() {
  let input = document.getElementById('todoInput').value;  
  let checkbox = document.createElement("input")
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox'
  let label = document.createElement("label")
  label.textContent = input
  label.appendChild(checkbox)
  let output = document.getElementById('todoList');
  output.appendChild(label)
}
```

and updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mz9ecc3d/3/)

Comment: Down voted without a comment? The updated JSfiddle shows exactly what the opening question asked for. Care to state what is "wrong" with my answer?